# Does 2 ^ O(log log n) = O(log n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Does `2 ^ O(log log n) = O(log n)`? Could you explain how to test this relationship?

I have tried substituting O(log(log n)) by `C1 log(log n)` and `log n` by `C2 log n` to find the relationship between them. When I graph the functions it seems that the statement is true, but I get stuck in the mathematical proof at one point and am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Assuming a base-2 log, then

2<sup>log log N</sup> = log N,

but 2<sup>10 log log N</sup> is also in 2<sup>O(log log N)</sup>, and

2<sup>10 log log N</sup> = (2<sup>log log N</sup>)<sup>10</sup> = (log N)<sup>10</sup>

...and that is obviously not in O(log N)

Comment: I am not sure why 2log log N = log N?

Comment: 2^(log x) = x.  Substitute x = log N

Comment: Thank you! Wish to see you on CS.stackexchange as your answers are very clear

Answer (score 2):

You are in a right direction. You can replace `O(log(log n))` with `c log(log n)` and be sure that there exists a constant `c` that `2 ^ O(log(log n)) < 2 ^ (c log(log n))`. Hence, we will have `S = 2^ (c log(log n)) =  (2^(log(log n)))^c = log(n)^c`. However, you **can't** say `S = O(log n)`. As `c` could be any constant number, you can say `S = O(n^epsilon)` that `epsilon` could be a small constant near to zero.

Comment: I had assumed that because the graph of log n was above the value of 2 ^ (loglogn) after a certain value of n, the statement was going to be true. But I understand the logic of what why it is false. Thanks!